# QUICKSTART WITH GEOMESA REDIS

Tags: redis, geomesa

Its my first time to try [geomesa](https://www.geomesa.org/) with redis,accroding to offical quickstart tutorial,I try:

```
mvn clean install -pl geomesa-tutorials-redis/geomesa-tutorials-redis-quickstart -am
```

It work normally:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for GeoMesa Tutorials and Examples 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] GeoMesa Tutorials and Examples ..................... SUCCESS [  0.900 s]
[INFO] GeoMesa Tutorials - Common ......................... SUCCESS [  2.101 s]
[INFO] GeoMesa Tutorials - Redis .......................... SUCCESS [  0.221 s]
[INFO] GeoMesa Tutorials - Redis - Quick Start ............ SUCCESS [  5.903 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

But when I try to run it:

```
java -cp geomesa-tutorials-redis/geomesa-tutorials-redis-quickstart/target/geomesa-tutorials-redis-quickstart-$VERSION.jar \
    org.geomesa.example.redis.RedisQuickStart \
    --redis.url localhost:6379 --redis.catalog geomesa
```

It shows:

```
error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geomesa.example.redis.RedisQuickStart
```

All codes run in root path(../geomesa-tutorials),what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `$VERSION` with the version of GeoMesa that you build, e.g.:

```
$ git checkout tag/geomesa-tutorials-2.4.0
$ mvn clean install -pl geomesa-tutorials-redis/geomesa-tutorials-redis-quickstart -am
$ java -cp geomesa-tutorials-redis/geomesa-tutorials-redis-quickstart/target/geomesa-tutorials-redis-quickstart-2.4.0.jar \
    org.geomesa.example.redis.RedisQuickStart \
    --redis.url localhost:6379 --redis.catalog geomesa
```